# Update file in SVN repository with changes made in local copy

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, commit

I know this is a newbie question, but I can't seem to be able to accomplish this except for first copying my modified file to another location, `svn remove modified_file`, copying file back to location, then `svn add modified_file` and then `svn commit`.

Is there an easier way to make update the repo with changes made in my working copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `svn commit`.  Its help text (from running `svn help commit`) states:

> commit (ci): Send changes from your working copy to the repository.

In other words, your modified file is considered a change and running commit will send that change to the repository.

This is perhaps one of the most basic parts of the workflow of SVN (or any version control software), and so of course there will be a simple and direct way to do it.

You should read up on the basic Subversion workflow either in the [Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.commit) (primary Subversion reference) or via [any other tutorial you can find](https://www.google.com/search?q=subversion+tutorial).